# Clarification needed for an exercise concerning inverse limit in basic group theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

*Background:*

**Exercise:** Recall that $F_{n,m}([a]_n)=[a]_m$ defines $F_{n,m}:\mathbb{Z}_n\to \mathbb{Z}_\mathbb{m}$ iff $m\mid n.$  When $p$ is a prime and $j\geq i,$ for convenience set $g_{j,i}=F_{p^j, p^i},$ Consider the group $G=\prod \mathbb{Z}_{p^t}$ over $i\in \mathbb{N}$, and set $H=\{f\in G\mid \text{ whenever } j\geq i, g_{j,i}(f(j))=f(i)\}.$ $H$ is called the **inverse limit** of $\{\mathbb{Z}_{p^i}\}$. It may be easier to consider $f\in G$ to be given by $f(i)=[f_i]\in \mathbb{Z}_{p^i}$ for representative $f_i\in \{0,1,2,\ldots, p^i - 1\}.$  Thus, $H=\{f\in G\mid \text{ whenever } j\geq i, f_j\equiv f_i \pmod {p^i}\}$.

*(i)*  Show that $H$ makes sense: that is, it unambiguously defines elements of $G.$  (The problem is that $H$ is defined by conditions on all pairs of its coordinates, but it has infinitely many coordinates, so one must check that the conditions are consistent.

*Questions:*

For the above exercise, I would like to know what i have to do to show that $H$ defines elements of $G$.  I don't understand when it says that I have to show that $H$ defines elements of $G$. In the bracket explanation, it says the reader have to check that the conditions are consistent which I do not understand what it means.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This problem is badly stated, you should complain to your instructor if this is from a class. What you need to check is that the system of maps $g_{ij}$ is an [inverse system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit).

Comment: Recall that, as you have repeatedly been told, **you should not use MathJax to format text**. You should not force colors either, especially black. If someone has their screen formatted for white letters on black background, for example (for accesibility reasons), when you force black color text using matjax the text would disappear. If they have the screen formatted to large text, the text you format with mathjax will not size properly. Stop it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You mean the following:  Let $\mathbb{Z}_n=A_j,$ $\mathbb{Z}_m=A_i,$ and $F_{n,m}=f_{ij}$ for all $m\leq n,$ and $m\mid n.$
Also let the map $F_{p^i,p^i}: \mathbb{Z}_{p^i}\to \mathbb{Z}_{p^i}$ be defined by $g_{i,i}=F_{p^i,p^i},$ and $g_{i,i}(f(i))=f(i).$ We define for $i\leq j,$ $g_{i,j}=F_{p^i,p^j},$ $g_{i,h}(f(j))=f(i),$ and for $j\leq k$ $g_{j,k}=F_{p^j,p^k},$ $g_{j,k}(f(j))=f(k).$  I then show that $F_{p^i,p^k}=F_{p^i,p^j}\circ F_{p^j,p^k},$ for $i\leq j\leq k.$

Comment: Of course......

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry, am I understanding you correctly in what I need to do to show that the $g_{i,j}$ map satisfies the criteria for an inverse system?